# ASP.NET API Controller null Category/Table

Tags: asp.net

I have a weird problem, I have Ajax calling an API that will delete/add to a database.

On the index onget I have debugged to check to make sure _context has the category initialized, and it does. However when I call the API _context is declared/intialized, but the table in question is now null. How do I make sure the table is not null.

I have the dbSet set like this:

```
        public DbSet<T> dbset { get; set; }
```

I can provide more syntax but not sure exactly this would be declared also. Would it be something in the startup.cs file? (I have multiple projects)

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Comment: have you initialize useSqlserver connection string? .. just a wild guess

Comment: It is. I know it's connecting and reading data. If I inspect that table inside of the onget() of that page it works, but the API (different project) it breaks. Do I need to add something to pass that info into the api?

Comment: so your API is indifferent project and onget() page  is in different project?

Comment: Correct. So I have the master project with all of the pages and what not. Then I have a project for the data control. So on the page ajax is calling the api. Which I think is why Category is null cause it has no idea what to initialize it to.

Comment: you need to add `services.AddDbContext` in your API project at the startup.

Comment: I added in my connection string, do you mind showing how to do it with multiple projects?

Comment: For multiple project you have to add it at startup.cs only

Comment: So as long as I have what I posted above I should be fine?

Comment: yes, you need to do it for every executable project.